# Build Android for shamu(Nexus 6)

Tags: android, android-source, nexus6

I followed [Aosp guide](https://source.android.com/source/building.html) and [XDA guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2974055) and try to build my first ROM for Nexus 6. I checked out android-7.0.0_r27 branch, Then I downloaded all driver binaries and extract them in `vendor/` directory of the root of the project. Then I ran this

```
make clobber && source build/envsetup.sh && lunch aosp_shamu-userdebug && make -j8 otapackage
```

And this is the error I get

```
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
[ 99% 455/456] glob vendor/*/*/Android.bp
ninja: error: 'out/target/product/shamu/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/copybit.msm8084_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/shamu/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libOmxVenc_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
build/core/ninja.mk:84: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (54 seconds) ####
```

I don't have any idea what is wrong! Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what was the problem, but after checking out to `android-7.0.0_r24` branch and `sync` that, I installed these packages on `Ubuntu 16.10`

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 \
lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache \
libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
```

which is the [requirements](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) of `Ubuntu 14.04`, now I can build the source successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had similar problem but with difference pathes. Installing packages as above didn't solved my problem. Problem was that **repo sync** hadn't properly synchronised all necessary git repositories but no error message was shown during executing **repo sync**.
What I did: from the message I entered the shown directory and typed **git status** -the directory was empty and full of removed files, so I typed **git reset --hard**, after that build moved one step further, so I redo this steps.
Faster way I've used was to find all empty directories:

```
find -empty -type d | vgrep '.repo' | xargs -n 1 readlink -f
```

and run in all of them **git reset --hard**.
It solved my problem.